# Compiling two files with RequireJS Optimize

Tags: requirejs, build-process

I am trying to specify compilation for two files in the build.js file for RequireJS optimizer. But only the last file gets optimized. Here's the build.js file:

```
({
    baseUrl: "..",
    name: "client/TestA",
    out: "full.js",
    findNestedDependencies: true
},{
    baseUrl: "..",
    name: "client/TestB",
    out: "fullB.js",
    findNestedDependencies: true
})
```

In this case only the last entry `client/TestB` is getting built. I need the require Optimizer to build both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you found this format of build.js file? Maybe you need something like [modules field](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L338)?

It should be something like this:

```
({

    baseUrl: "..",
    dir : './out' // required when using modules, instead 'out' field
    modules: [
        {
            name: "client/TestA"
        },
        {
            name: "client/TestB"
        }
    ],
    findNestedDependencies: true
});
```